# Is $\mathrm{d} \pi (x,y)$ or $\pi(x,y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$ correct in Optimal Transport formulation?

Tags: probability-distributions, optimal-transport

The Kantorovich formulation of optimal transport sometimes looks like this

$$\mathrm{inf} \int_{E \times E} C(x, y) \ d \pi(x, y)$$

and sometimes looks like this

$$\mathrm{inf} \int_{E \times E} C(x, y) \  \pi(x, y) \hspace{1mm} dx \hspace{1mm} dy $$

both being subject to the usual constraints
$$\int_E \pi(x, y) dy = \mu(x) \qquad \int_E \pi(x, y) dx = \nu(y)$$

What is the difference, and which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get from the first formula to the second if you assume that the measure $\pi$ has a Lebesgue density on $E\times E$, called by abuse of notation again $\pi$. Then $d\pi(x,y)=\pi(x,y)dxdy$. It is however, not a good idea to impose that π should have a Lebesgue density, because in the most important examples, related to Monge's problem the optimal $\pi$ will actually be singular. In short, the first formula is the better.

Comment: so the Lebesque matrix $\pi$ is surely to be singular (non-invertible)? What makes the non-Lebesque matrix invertible in comparison?

Comment: Well, in it's standard formulation of OT you minimise over all $\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)$, couplings between $\mu$ and $\nu$. In particluar one does not ask for couplings which have Lebesgue density. And as I said, the optimal $\pi^{*}$ for the problem typically is given by $d\pi^{*}(x,y)=d\mu(x)\delta_{T(x)}(dy)$, i.e. is singular and does not admit a Lebesgue density.  Regarding the matrix setting in computional optimal transport: there also also you minimise over matrices $P$ of which you don't ask a priori that they are invertible (which makes sense only in the $n\times n$ case anyway).